# Step by step iphone debugging on xcode shows nothing on screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I realize it doesn't work because it needs to print on the screen, but...

Is there anyway and/or a good simple way to actually just press "step over" or "step into" and see the command output on the device/simulator screen?

I want to keep pressing it and be able to see what every step do on the screen as quick as possible, if that's even a possibility for iphone debugging.

*<sup>I hope while short this question still is pretty clear and not a duplicate! :P</sup>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the iPhone simulator UI is not refreshed immediately. The UI framework don't update the screen at each instruction. You can try a manual [myView setNeedDisplay:YES] (or something like that) after each step.

Comment: sorry for taking so long, this seems promising... I will try it in few days and report back. ;)

Comment: well "few days" later, I couldn't manage doing it and now I'm not dealing with xcode anymore... so, sorry for lame report. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at [CFRunLoop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html) to try and force UI updates in different runloops, although that is about the extent of my understanding of the API.

Comment: could you give an example on how to use this?

Comment: like I said, I've never actually used it, just read a bit about it. you could try and use higher-level APIs that use it (like `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) with a delay of 0 to force a new runloop.